# TypeError: Failed to fetch despite Postman returning a correct data

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to get this API working on one of my react native project and I keep getting failed to fetch errors.
This is the code

```
let url = "API endpoint";

let headers = {
  Authorization:
    "working bearer token"
};

fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: headers,
  body: null
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

When I try this on a postman, it works just fine and returns correct data.

When the data is coming from API that is [] empty array, the fetch works again. But when there is a large data, I get a fetch error.

How can I solve this issue?
Thank you

EDIT: To add, it is definitely not a CORS issue.

Comment: What error fo you get when its a large fetch? We cant help you without it

Comment: what error it trigger ?. might be api not returning valid json